# How to add money denominations c++

Tags: c++, currency

very new programmer, I am having a difficult time trying to find a way to set up this problem. I have money denominations , one dollar through one hundred dollar. A user must input lets say for example 4 one dollar, and 5 five dollar, and receive a sum of 29 dollars. I am at a loss, I have been trying here is what i have...

```
{   // dollar values 

    int n = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int b = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int dollarOne = 1;
    int dollarTwo = 2;
    int sum1;                                               // defines sum 


    cin >> n >> dollarOne; 
    sum1 = ((n*dollarOne)+(b*dollarTwo);                                // sum function 


    cout << sum1 << endl;                               // displays total amount


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

*New*
        int dollarAm1;
        int dollarAm2; 
        int sum; 
        cin >> dollarAm1;
        cin >> dollarAm2; 
        sum = ((dollarAm1 * 1) + (dollarAm2 * 2));

```
    cout << sum << endl;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `dollarTwo` equal 5? Doesn't that represent a $5? I could be reading it wrong though, not a C++ expert.

Comment: Looks like a good task for *lookup* tables.  Have a table of `<string, value>` where value is $100 for "hundred".  Search the table for the string and extract the value.

Comment: Yes, `dollarTwo` should be 5 instead of 2. Also, the user is not being allowed to enter how many five dollars to use, only how many one dollars to use.  The number of five dollars is being set to max int instead.

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: If you are very new programmer try to learn and do it with C languange, using functions. Now (with C++) you are trying to drive a big containership, but never before drive a canoe :)

Comment: I think you would benefit greatly from stepping through the code line by line and watching what the program does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something more like this instead (error handling removed for brevity):

```
{
    int n;
    int sum1 = 0;

    cout << "How many $1 bills: ";
    cin >> n;
    sum1 += (n*1);

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    cout << "How many $5 bills: ";
    cin >> n;
    sum1 += (n*5);

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    cout << "How many $10 bills: ";
    cin >> n;
    sum1 += (n*10);

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    cout << "How many $20 bills: ";
    cin >> n;
    sum1 += (n*20);

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    cout << "How many $50 bills: ";
    cin >> n;
    sum1 += (n*50);

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    cout << "How many $100 bills: ";
    cin >> n;
    sum1 += (n*100);

    cout << "Total: $" << sum1 << endl;

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a parentheses

`sum1 = ((n*dollarOne)+(b*dollarTwo);`

Next, you should use `cin.get()` to end your programs, not `system("PAUSE")`. This is more effective in terms of processing speed. Also , you should simply do `int n, b;` to initialize the variables.

You should read input like so:

```
std::cout << "Enter number of 1-dollar bills, and press \"Enter\". Next, enter number of 5-dollar bills:" << std::endl;

cin >> dollarOne;
cin >> dollarTwo;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int n = 0;
int b = 0;
int dollarOne = 1;
int dollarFive = 5;
int sum1; // defines sum


std::cin >> n;
std::cin >> b;

sum1 = (n*dollarOne)+(b*dollarFive); // sum function


std::cout << sum1 << std::endl; // displays total amount


system("pause");
return 0;
```